# How to create collectible SPL Token

Tags: solana

Maybe somebody know, im searching for how i can create spl token which will be show in collectible items as nft. I created tokens, I also created an nft collection, and now I’m looking for how to make a token like nft (but not nft). So that after creating the token, by going to the Phantom wallet -> Collectibles, for example, I can see my tokens (not nft). I saw some guys managed to do this, it's interesting how.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the decimals to 0 using "--decimals 0"